# Podman error on RHEL 8.6 - OCI runtime error: runc: runc create failed:

Tags: containers, rhel, podman

We are running a RHEL 8.6 VM with Podman 4.1.1 installed.

```
$ podman version
Client:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.1.1
API Version:  4.1.1
Go Version:   go1.17.7
Built:        Wed Oct 12 08:42:59 2022
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

When we try to start our container, we receive this error.

```
$ ./start.sh
Error: OCI runtime error: runc: runc create failed: unable to start container process: waiting for init preliminary setup: read init-p: connection reset by peer
```

Whats interesting is this is intermittent.  If we hit up arrow and try to run the script again, about 1 out of every 8 times, we can enter the container.

podman info --debug shows:

```
name: runc
    package: runc-1.1.3-3.module+el8.6.0+16986+c8760fe3.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: |-
      runc version 1.1.3
      spec: 1.0.2-dev
      go: go1.17.12
      libseccomp: 2.5.2
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    path: /run/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: false
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: true
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.2.0-2.module+el8.6.0+16771+28dfca77.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.2.0
      commit: 656041d45cfca7a4176f6b7eed9e4fe6c11e8383
      libslirp: 4.4.0
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.2
  swapFree: 17179865088
  swapTotal: 17179865088
  uptime: 44m 13.35s
plugins:
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - passthrough
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  - ipvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  search:
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - registry.redhat.io
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /etc/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 120
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 120
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions:
    overlay.mountopt: nodev,metacopy=on
  graphRoot: /docker/storage
  graphRootAllocated: 442274021376
  graphRootUsed: 266936029184
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "true"
  imageCopyTmpDir: /var/tmp
  imageStore:
    number: 1
  runRoot: /docker/storage
  volumePath: /docker/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 4.1.1
  Built: 1665582179
  BuiltTime: Wed Oct 12 08:42:59 2022
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.17.7
  Os: linux
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 4.1.1
```

Do you all have any insight into this error?  Thanks!